# Scroll more data on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have an appointment table in html as follows:

```html
<table>
  <thead style="text-align:center; color:#000;">

    <th style="text-align:center;">Mon</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Tue</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Wed</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Thu</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Fri</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Sat</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="background:#ccc">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px">
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
        <li style="background:#eee; color:#000; border:solid 1px #ffb600; width:60px; padding:1px; list-style:none;">8.30</li>
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to add scroll but in an indirect way, on bottom of last `<li>` tag a show more button should be there.
**so that when i click on, td cell data should scroll up and rest of the data should show**

[image: Output]

Please guide if someone worked on this before?

Comment: I did some code but do not have time to finish it https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rw1sdLaj/

Answer (score 0):

There is another option called lazy loading, this feature is support in chrome browser, all we have to do is add a attribute to the html element .

```
<table loading="lazy"></table>
```

to read more check this link [lazy load](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/native-lazy-loading-launched-on-chrome-76)

Comment: And this works for table cells? I doubt that very much

Comment: this is not what i am looking for